plot many signals together in python
I am trying to plot many signals (196) from a multielectrode dataset (https://zenodo.org/records/1411883). I want to plot something cool to see all registers together. I want to get something similar to this:

Is there any python package or way that you would advice me to follow for plotting all this intormation?
I tried createing subplots but they are too small and take too much to generate.

plot(time, ch[nn] + off*nn) where off is some vertical offset in data space?

I have tried that but it takes too long and everything looks very dense... maybe it is just a matter of number of signals..

I think plotting 196 signals on the same plot is a bit too much.
Below is for 30 signals, using a computed offset:
EDIT: Added splitting across subplots and MultiCursor.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor


def main():
    n, t = 196, np.linspace(0, 10, 600)
    signals = create_signals(t, n) + create_signals(t, n) + create_signals(t, n)

    nmax_per_col = 30
    n_cols = n // nmax_per_col + bool(n % nmax_per_col)

    # Split signals into groups of almost same size
    signals_groups = np.array_split(signals, n_cols, axis=0)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=n_cols, sharex=True, figsize=(2.5 * n_cols, 8))
    for ax, signals_group in zip(axes, signals_groups):
        plot_multisignals(t, signals_group, ax=ax)

    # Need to keep "multi" alive
    multi = MultiCursor(None, tuple(axes.flat), color="r", lw=1)

    plt.show()


def plot_multisignals(t, signals, horizontal_lines=True, ax=None, **kwargs):
    """
    t: shape (N,)
    signals: shape (M, N)
    """
    if ax is None:
        _, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Center the signals and add offsets
    sigs = signals - signals.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    offset = np.max(sigs.max(axis=1)[:-1] - sigs.min(axis=1)[1:])
    sigs = sigs.T + np.arange(len(signals)) * offset

    ax.plot(t, sigs, **kwargs)
    if horizontal_lines:
        for i in range(len(signals) + 1):
            ax.axhline(i * offset - offset / 2, color="k", lw=0.5, alpha=0.3)

    # Remove y-axis labels because no meaning
    ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)
    return ax


def create_signals(t, n):
    # Dummy function to generate signals
    freqs = np.random.rand(n) * 3 + 1
    amps = np.random.rand(n) * 3.8 + 0.2
    signals = np.zeros((n, len(t)))
    for i, (freq, amp) in enumerate(zip(freqs, amps)):
        signals[i] = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)
    return signals


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This is great! This could work, I could divide the signals by sections and create different plots. Thanks for the answer! It does do the job!

You're welcome. Yes you can go like that, in that case don't forget the handy sharex argument to plt.subplots(ncols=..., sharex=True), and for exploration purpose take a look at the MultiCursor widget.

So I made an edit to implement those ideas.
